# Limiting RecursiveIteratorIterator() recursion depth

Tags: php, subdirectory

i'm using RecursiveIteratorIterator() to explore subfolders of my current path, but in this way all trhe tree is explored, instead i want just the direct childern of my fodler to be explored for files. How can i say to RecursiveIteratorIterator() to not go much further and stop to the first subfodlers of the current folder?

Following Lauri Lehtinen, i've tried this:

```
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("$directory");
    $it->setMaxDepth(1);
```

i have PHP 5.2.3 but it say me that setMaxDepth is undefined.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method RecursiveDirectoryIterator::setMaxDepth()

Comment: you're calling on RecursiveDirectoryIterator, not  RecursiveIteratorIterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`RecursiveIteratorIterator::setMaxDepth`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth.php) method to set your depth to `1` (or as many levels as you wish):

Answer (score 0):

As Lauri said, setting [RecursiveIteratorIterator::setMaxDepth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth.php) to 1 is the best approach.

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#91519 for the following example of how to use it:

```
<?php
$directory = "/tmp/";
$fileSPLObjects =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
            );
try {
    foreach( $fileSPLObjects as $fullFileName => $fileSPLObject ) {
        print $fullFileName . " " . $fileSPLObject->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
}
catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    printf("Directory [%s] contained a directory we can not recurse into", $directory);
}
?>
```

If you're having problems, be sure you're using PHP 5.1.0 or later.